# First Order ODE Notation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The topic is about equation representation of First Order ODE's.
I have two questions and then, if i'm right i have two other questions.

I - Am i right that any first order ODE can be represented by these 4 forms of equation ?

1 : $f(y',y,x) = 0 $

2 :$ y' = f(y,x)$

3:  $y' + h(x,y) = 0 $                     // By choosing $h(x,y) = -f(y,x)$

4:  M(x,y)y' + N(x,y) = 0                // By choosing M(x,y) = 1 and N(x,y) = -f(x,y)

II - Am i also right that any first order linear ODE can be written in these 2 forms of equation ?

1 : $a(x)y' + b(x)y + c(x) = 0 $

2 : $y' + d(x)y + e(x)  $                 // By making $d(x) = \frac{b(x)}{a(x)}$ and $e(x) = \frac{c(x)}{a(x)}$

If i'm right, I can clearly see there was a transition ( particularization ) of I-3 equation into II-2 equation and of  I-4 equation into II-1 equation given that the ODE is llinear.

The first transition would imply that if the ODE is linear then h(x,y) can be written as d(x)y + e(x).My question is why exactly? ( i want to fully understand why having no non-linear components of y in $h(x,y)$ requires that it must be decomposed into d(x)y + e(x) ).

The second transition would imply that if the ODE is linear then M(x,y) is only function of x, resulting $a(x)$, and it would also imply that $N(x,y) $( just like h(x,y) ) can be decomposed into b(x)y + c(x) ( a function of x, times y, plus a function of x ). My question is ... Why exactly are these requirements (as a result of a linear case ) upon $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ ? .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think not. Take
$$ y' + e^{y'} + \sin(y') = y $$
and you can't isolate $y'$ from that expression. Hence, it can't be written in the form I.(2). However, this equation is clearly not linear.

Comment: Can't we expand e^y'   and  sin(y')  with Taylor series and then isolate y' approaching infinity steps?

Comment: @LinAlgMan How is that equation not I-1 ($f(y',y,x)=0$)?

Comment: I think LingAlgMan is saying y′+ey′+sin(y′)=y  can  be represented in I-1 (f(y′,y,x)=0)   but not in I-2 ( y′=f(y,x) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following forms are the same to showe a first order ODE:

- $F(x,y,y')=0,~~~ x\in I=(a,b)$
- $y'=f(x,y),~~~ x\in I=(a,b)$
- For  a proper function $N(x,y)$ and $M(x,y)$, $y'=f(x,y)=\frac{M(x,y)}{-N(x,y)},~~~ x\in I=(a,b)$ and so $$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$

And the following forms are applied to show a first order **linear** ODE:

- $a_1(x)y'+a_0(x)y=g(x),~~~ x\in I=(a,b)$
- and if for all $x\in I,~ a_1(x)\neq 0$ then $$y'+\frac{a_0(x)}{a_1(x)}y=\frac{g(x)}{a_1(x)}$$

But we cannot always convert these two categories to each other preserving their subject.

Comment: Can we represent y′+ey′+sin(y′)=y   in   y′=f(x,y) form ?

Comment: @user1843665: The problem here is that if you want to show the OE explicitly or implicitly. $f$ is not the same necessarily as $F$.

Comment: But wouldnt y′=f(x,y) require that we show the OE implicitly whereas F(x,y,y′)=0 doesn't require that we show it implictly ? 
Can we show  y′+ey′+sin(y′)=y     implicitly ?

Comment: @user1843665: Yes, it is right. In fact, the identity  $y′+e^{y′}+\sin(y′)-y=0$ itself defines a relation $F$.

Comment: The result is that we can always represent a first order ODE by F(x,y,y')  but not always by y' = f(x,y) ?

Comment: @user1843665: As far as I have seen in many books, we always prefer ODE to be presented as $y'=f(x,y)$ at least in the first chapters, however, the first form also define a first order ODE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7855/discussion-between-user1843665-and-babak-s)

Comment: Nice!! And thanks for taking the time to work answer all the questions in comments! +1